# Does HDOP correlate with GPS position accuracy?

Tags: gps, accuracy

I collected 1000+ position data from GPS receivers and realized that a position with lower HDOP does not necessarily have higher accuracy.
So my question is does HDOP correlate with GPS position accuracy?

Comment: Did you collect the GPS data with a ground station (DGPS)? That will give you higher positional accuracy.

Comment: No I did not, but I will try that in near future.

Comment: What made you "realize[d]" this?  Please describe how you came to this position, and the data to explain it.

Comment: I want to eliminate the possibly incorrect GPS data by looking at DOP values, but since it does not seem to correlate with the accuracy, I posted this question.

Comment: I just looked at the position of several data points and their DOP values, and saw that sometimes data points with higher accuracy had higher HDOP than the ones with lower accuracy,

Comment: Would recommend investing in a device that can receive Dual Band GPS - GPS frequencies are called L1 and L5, while Galileo frequencies are called E1 and E5a. With good satellite fixes you can get sub 30cm accuracy.  (more recent smartphones have this GPS chipset as standard)

Comment: HDOP value is calculated by the positions of GPS satellites https://gisgeography.com/gps-accuracy-hdop-pdop-gdop-multipath/ but there are also other factors which have an effect on the accuracy. You deal also with statistical deviations, if accuracy is typically plus minus 5 meters every now and the error is much smaller, and sometimes higher.